# How to filter XML string by element "paths" in Groovy or Java

Tags: java, xml, groovy, sax

I have an object that's currently mapped from a Java POJO to XML using JAXB.  Once I have that XML, I occasionally need to whittle it down to only a select set of elements based on input by a user.  The result should be XML with ONLY the specified "fields".

I've come across a number of similar use cases which us SAX Filters, but they seem very complicated and the answers don't quite get me where I need. The closest example is [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipstx2/index.html), which excludes a single path from the result.  I want the opposite -- whitelist a select list of elements.

Example object:  School.xml

```
<SchoolInfo RefId="34060F68BE3942F1B1264E6D2CC3C353">
        <LocalId>57</LocalId>
        <SchoolName>Foobar School of Technology</SchoolName>
        <Principal>
           <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
           <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        </Principal>
        <StateProvinceId>34573</StateProvinceId>
        <LEAInfoRefId>340666687E3942F1B1264E1223453C353</LEAInfoRefId>
        <PhoneNumberList>
           <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
              <Number>555-832-5555</Number>
           </PhoneNumber>
           <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
              <Number>555-999-5555</Number>
           </PhoneNumber>
        </PhoneNumberList>
     </SchoolInfo>
```

Given the following input as a "filter":

```
List<String> filter = [ 
    "LocalId",
    "SchoolName",
    "Principal/FirstName",
    "PhoneNumberList/PhoneNumber/Number",
 ]
```

I need the output to be:

```
<SchoolInfo RefId="34060F68BE3942F1B1264E6D2CC3C353">
    <LocalId>57</LocalId>
    <SchoolName>Foobar School of Technology</SchoolName>
    <Principal>
       <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    </Principal>
    <PhoneNumberList>
        <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
            <Number>555-832-5555</Number>
        </PhoneNumber>
        <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
            <Number>555-999-5555</Number>
        </PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumberList>
</SchoolInfo>
```

What is the best library to achieve this?  SAX Filtering feels to complicated, and XSLT doesn't seem like a good fit given the dynamic filtering.

Examples to help me get closer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `Groovy` should be good with `XmlParser` or `MarkupBuild`. See some sample [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2011/05/groovy-goodness-change-xml-structure.html)

Comment: Are you looking for code sample that accomplishes this or merely seeking recommendations on libs?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author A code sample would be amazing, but I'm not asking anyone to do the work for me.  Advice on the right library to use and the method within that library is what I'm looking for.

Comment: your definition of filtering is somewhat unclear to me... if under the phonenumber element, there is another element called address... which your filter does not address, should it be retained?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author The filter needs to be a "whitelist".  So, only keep the elements that are included.  What I'm not sure about is the _attributes_, but I can figure that out once the elements themselves.  In this case, the address element wouldn't be included.  It does get tricky if you were to ask for "PhoneNumberList/PhoneNumber" though.  In that case, all child elements of PhoneNumber should be included.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that does the white listing... it is based on XPath and VTD-XML. Its output has indentation issues... this is the first pass that emphasizes correctness...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class whiteList {

    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        List <String> filter = Arrays.asList("LocalId",
                "SchoolName",
                "Principal/FirstName",
                "PhoneNumberList/PhoneNumber/Number");
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\schoolInfo.xml", false)){
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        FastIntBuffer fib = new FastIntBuffer();
        // build a bitmap for the entire token pool consisting of elements
        int i,k;
        for (i=0;i<vn.getTokenCount();i++){
            if (vn.getTokenType(i)==VTDNav.TOKEN_STARTING_TAG){
                fib.append(0x1);// b'11 since it is a white list,
            }else{
                fib.append(0);
            }
        }
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        AutoPilot ap1= new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap1.selectXPath("descendant::*");// mark descendant as keep
        for (int j=0;j<filter.size();j++){
            ap.selectXPath(filter.get(j));
            while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                fib.modifyEntry(i, 0x3);
                vn.push();
                do{
                    if( vn.getTokenDepth(vn.getCurrentIndex())>=0)
                       fib.modifyEntry(vn.getCurrentIndex(), 0x3);
                    else
                        break;
                }while(vn.toElement(VTDNav.P));
                vn.pop();
                vn.push();
                while((k=ap1.evalXPath())!=-1){
                    fib.modifyEntry(k, 0x3);
                }
                ap1.resetXPath();
                vn.pop();
            }
            ap.resetXPath();
        }

        //remove those not on the whitelist
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        for (int j=0;j<fib.size();j++){
            if (fib.intAt(j)==0x1){
                vn.recoverNode(j);
                xm.remove();
            }
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\newSchoolInfo.xml");                    
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm testing this now.  One immediate modification is I need to read from a String, and output as a String.  I'm assuming I can use ByteArrayInputStream and its equivalent?

Comment: This actually results in a `NullPointerException` for me when I call xm.output on a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  I'm having a hard time following the execution, but it looks like there are no VTD tokens when it tries to write the output?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? To read from a string, you need to convert into a byte array, which is easy to do (getBytes))... and here is a  blog post showing you how to parse xml from an array of bytes...https://ximpleware.wordpress.com/2016/06/02/parsefile-vs-parse-a-quick-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

All Groovy:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xml = '''<SchoolInfo RefId="34060F68BE3942F1B1264E6D2CC3C353">
    <LocalId>57</LocalId>
    <SchoolName>Foobar School of Technology</SchoolName>
    <Principal>
       <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
       <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Principal>
    <StateProvinceId>34573</StateProvinceId>
    <LEAInfoRefId>340666687E3942F1B1264E1223453C353</LEAInfoRefId>
    <PhoneNumberList>
       <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
          <Number>555-832-5555</Number>
       </PhoneNumber>
       <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
          <Number>555-999-5555</Number>
       </PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumberList>
 </SchoolInfo>'''

def node = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

def whitelist = [ 'LocalId', 'SchoolName', 'Principal/FirstName', "PhoneNumberList/PhoneNumber/Number" ]*.split('/')

def void loveRemovalMachine(node, whitelist) {
    def elementNamesToKeep = whitelist*.head()
    println "Retaining nodes ${elementNamesToKeep} for node $node"
    def nodesToRemove = node.'*'.findAll { child -> !elementNamesToKeep.contains(child.name()) }
    nodesToRemove.each { node.remove it }
    def nextWhitelist = whitelist*.tail().findAll { it }
    println "Next level: $nextWhitelist"
    if (!nextWhitelist) {
        return
    }
    // The "*" operator seems to return text nodes...very stupid.
    node.'*:*'.each { loveRemovalMachine it, nextWhitelist }
}

loveRemovalMachine node, whitelist

XmlUtil.serialize node
```

Comment: Output: 

```Result: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SchoolInfo RefId="34060F68BE3942F1B1264E6D2CC3C353">
  <LocalId>57</LocalId>
  <SchoolName>Foobar School of Technology</SchoolName>
  <Principal>
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Principal>
  <PhoneNumberList>
    <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
      <Number>555-832-5555</Number>
    </PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber Type="0096">
      <Number>555-999-5555</Number>
    </PhoneNumber>
  </PhoneNumberList>
</SchoolInfo>
```

Comment: Of course this can be done in Java; please advise if you want such a code sample. It's the same idea: a recursive method that cleans up the DOM. It's just gonna be much more verbose in Java.